# What are some methods for comparing 2 separate quantile regression curves?

Tags: multiple-regression, quantile-regression

I am currently working with a dataset using the QuantregGrowth package in RStudio to determine the 2.5th/97.5th percentile curves of a biomarker across the age spectrum. I have a pretty good handle on this now, but my next step is trying to figure out if there are any sex differences. I was planning to make two separate regression curves for males and females and then compare them but I am having trouble finding a statistical method/R package to accomplish this. Does anyone know a good way to do this? If not, (or if this is not the best way to determine sex differences), can anyone help me with how to incorporate sex using the QuantregGrowth package and determine if it has a significant effect?

Edit: For further clarification, the purpose of this analysis is to create reference intervals for this biomarker and I want to determine if sexes require different intervals or not, based on whether there is a statistical difference in the data.

Comment: If you have a quantile regression model, can you not add a sex dummy just like you would in an ordinary regression model?

Comment: I second the recommendation to use one regression that includes `sex` as a variable, perhaps interacting with the other variables.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I can add it into the model as a variable however my big problem is figuring out how to extract from the outputs on R whether there is a significant effect/difference with sex. For further clarification, the purpose of this analysis is to create reference intervals for this biomarker and the question of sex is to determine if different sexes require different intervals or not. I will edit the main question to clarify this.